# I need custom user role in wordpress with only few capabilities

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin. And I need a custom user role with only access to two custom post type. I already tried many solutions, but I still have options in the dashboard "pages", "posts" although I restricted user role only on few capabilities.
So I have two custom post type which is exhibition and application. I need only that two options in the dashboard when user login, nothing else.

Comment: Better to ask this on the WP StackOverflow... here's a similar question that you could tailor to your needs: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96910/restrict-custom-post-type-view-by-user-role it's a bit dated though.

Comment: Thank you on fast answer, I will try it.